# OpenWRT noack and mcs rate

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, openwrt, tcpip, 802.11n

Are different MCS rates supported when you are running in noack mode?

**Context:** I am using ath9k modems+Compex WPQ864 (linux-ipq864) boards. I have configured one of the boards as Access point and other one as station. I have connected them on wlan and ping works. I am trying to turn off ack using:

```
iw dev wlan1 set noack_map 0xff
```

And I tried to modify MCS rates using:

```
iw dev wlan1 set bitrates ht-mcs-5 7
```

But this works as intended when ack is on, but has no effect when I turn off ack using the above noack_map command. And the rate is always at 6Mbps.

```
iw wlan1 station dump
```

shows the following output:

```
inactive time:  570 ms
rx bytes:       190293
rx packets:     1700
tx bytes:       187747
tx packets:     1621
tx retries:     0
tx failed:      883
rx drop misc:   1
signal:         -37 [-44, -38] dBm
signal avg:     -36 [-43, -37] dBm
tx bitrate:     6.0 MBit/s
rx bitrate:     13.0 MBit/s MCS 1rx drop misc:   1
signal:         -37 [-44, -38] dBm
signal avg:     -36 [-43, -37] dBm
tx bitrate:     6.0 MBit/s
rx bitrate:     13.0 MBit/s MCS 1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you using noack modes? Btw these bitrates are extremely bad for the signal strength output of **iw wlan1 station dump**.

Comment: Turning off the ack is an absolute requirement to achieve a goal for overall system.

Comment: Now I'm very curious: What *is* the goal for the overall system that requires turning off ack's? And I guess you'll have to read the ath9k driver source to find an answer, OpenWRT very likely has no influence on this.

Comment: Oh, everybody's curious about the goal :) It's the delay, dude! Sometimes you can afford losing a packet, but cannot afford the stream to get stuck even for a few milliseconds. It will increase jitter and bite your ass if you're doing VoIP or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Lucky you! I'm trying to create a low-delay channel for video. Every method I've tried to suppress Acks (packet injection, QoS, noack_map 0x01) works, but is dropping my data rate down to 1 Mbps.

You could try NoAck'ing one socket instead of the whole interface (this is C, I've tried to do this via iptables' `set-tos` option, but didn't figure out how it works):

```
int priority = 262;  // Wifi QoS priority Video (VI)
if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_PRIORITY, (const char *)&priority, sizeof(priority)) < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt SO_PRIORITY");
}
```

It will give your socket priority 6 (VI aka Video) in `QoS Control` field of 802.11 header. Then use this:

```
iw dev wlan0 set noack_map 0x00C0
```

to enable NoAck for this socket. This should've been the proper way of doing it, but for me the data rate of these NoAcked frames was hard nailed to 1 Mbps despite of `iw dev set bitrates` and `iw dev set mcast_rate`. Maybe you would be luckier.